# Return entry is convertible to T that satisfies predicate

Tags: c#

I have code such as:

```
m_Grabbed = ((IGetGrabbedSMB)a_From.Find(x => x is IGetGrabbedSMB)).GetGrabbed();
```

Now I want to create a generic `Find` which filters on T & applies the predicate, which gives me something like:

```
public static T1 Find< T1, T2 >( this List< T2 > a_This, Predicate< T1 > a_Match )
where T2 : class
where T1 : class
{
   return (T1)a_This.Find(x => x is T1 && a_Match( (T1)x ) );
}
```

This however is a no go because the constraints doesn't say anything about T1 being convertible to T2. Sadly it doesn't seem to be possible to constrain to interface instead, which I would assume would make this work. Is there any approach which would allow me to write a generic which could make this work?

Comment: You seem to be essentially redoing `Enumerable.OfType`, and then trying to combine this with another predicate at the same time. I'd just write `...OfType<...>().Where(...)`.

Comment: I should've looked further because that actually works nicely with what I'm actually trying to do.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Write this as an answer so it can be accepted.